# HTML/CSS image scaling

Tags: html, css

I'm writing my own cms system with an fixed userbar, but i have a problem with the images in the userbar:

It should look like this
[image]

But it looks like this
[image]

I defined the bar in css like this:

```
#userbar {
    background-color:#969696;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    position:fixed;
}

#navcont {
    padding: 5px 100px 5px;
}

#content {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

#options ul li a {
    padding: 5px 300px 5px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    position:fixed;
    list-style: none;
    /*list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-position: outside;*/
}
```

```
<div id='userbar'>
    <div id='navcont'>
        <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION["userID"])) {
                //Daten auslesen
            }
            else {
                echo("Sie sind nicht angemeldet.");
                echo("<div id='options'><ul style='list-style-item:none;'><li><a href='login'><img src='img/loginOptionsS.png' height='16px' width='16px'>Anmelden</a></li></ul></div>");
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i created a js fiddle and i dont see the problem - you might change the style of your ul / li elements - i still see the list element on the li element. You could also try to change the image style in your css with #options ul li a img { width: 16px; height: 16px; } instead of in your html code.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need px with the height and width of img - just height='16' width='16' - is fine...otherwise try this.  Not sure if you have some img css somewhere that is overwriting your img scale though.

```css
#userbar {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #969696;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;

}


#options {
  display: inline-block;
}


#navcont {
  padding: 7px 100px 7px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
}


#content {
  padding-top: 5px;
}


#options ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}


#options ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  list-style: none;
}


#options ul li a img {
  margin-right: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id='userbar'>
    <div id='navcont'>Sie sind nicht angemeldet.
        <div id='options'>
            <ul style='list-style:none;'>
                <li><a href='login'><img src='http://placehold.it/16x16.jpg' height='16' width='16'>Anmelden</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't help. I have the body-tag defined like this:
body {
 min-width:1024px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

Comment: Your body tag css wouldn't change this code result.  If you have a link somewhere to check I can help you - You may have some other css somewhere that is causing conflicts to your code and therefore you need more specificity.  But you should see here this code works.